# How to import in MT5 the numPy functions?

Tags: numpy, performance, loops, mql5

I am using MT5 and want to import the function numpy.intersect1d to detect if array1 is subset of array2, faster than the for loops.
I am a bit lost how to import that function. Any clue I will appreciate it.

I tried with the function matrix in MT5 but is so slow getting each Row as vector by using vector.Compare.

Comment: Importing a function in isolation does not make sense.  You need the whole numpy package.  See the [source] link in the function's docs to see what it uses (`asarray`, `unique`, `sort`, `ravel`)